# Ruby Method for Casting

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby development and I am making a simple chat server encrypted over TLS.

I have managed to get the basic server running however I now want to add special properties to each of the connected clients (username, etc.)

I have this class which I plan to use for each client that connects:

```
class Client < OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket
    attr_accessor :username
    ...
end
```

I need to get a `Client` object from the `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.accept` function in order to set the username attribute. I am used to C type languages where casting would do the trick but Google has told me that this is not the case in Ruby.

What is the Ruby way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need casting in Ruby. It's a dynamic language. So what matters is if the object knows how to respond to a message (method).

Comment: Well then I guess I am asking: how then do I get the object to know how to respond to the message?

Comment: I never used raw sockets in ruby. Here are some examples with tcp sockets. I suspect it should be almost the same with sslsockets. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm

Comment: I am not having trouble with sockets. I want to know if I can add a `username` attribute to a socket. Apparently not. Would the best way to do this create a Client with a `socket` and `username` attribute?

Comment: I am also using raw sockets because I want the server to run on an obscure port.

Comment: Ohh. Now I understood your question. The way you are trying to do it seems problematic because when you accept a socket you get a OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket and not a Client. You could simply save the username elsewhere and map it to the socket. For example you could have a simple class to store the socket and the username.

Comment: Subclassing the SSLSocket class seems really a NOT solution to this in ruby.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you. Although it is not applicable here for future reference is there any way to get an object to respond to a subclasses methods?

Comment: You just can't do that. You need to create the object with the subclass. You can add methods to a class with some tricks like delegation, or metaprogramming but there is nothing like casting that you have in static languages

Comment: Ok that you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. delegation: create Client as a wrapper with an instance variable of class OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket. Client would then have to understand and forward messages to SSLSocket. Could get complicated.
2. extension: use class_eval to add instance variables and/or methods directly to SSLSocket. This is a commonly-used Ruby approach.